# Writing permutation as a product of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I have a problem writing permutations as a product of disjoint cycles. For example, in the book, there are the following cycles:

$(132)=(13)(12)$,

$(1243)(243)=(23)(34)(14)$

Can someone please explain these two? Also, why does multiplying a transposition by itself gives the identity permutation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In product notation the permutations are normally applied from right to left. Be sure to distinguish the product of two permutations from the concatenation of cycles within a single permutation, by using a dot ($\cdot$) to signify 'product'.

Verify the second example on a string like $abcd$:
$$
abcd \stackrel{(243)}\to acdb\stackrel{(1243)}\to dabc
$$
is the same as:
$$
abcd\stackrel{(14)}\to dbca\stackrel{(34)}\to dbac\stackrel{(23)}\to dabc.
$$
This proves that $(1243)\cdot(243)=(23)\cdot(34)\cdot(14)$.

You have a typo in your first example. The assertion $(132)=(13)\cdot(12)$ is false, since
$$
abc\stackrel{(132)}\to bca
$$
while
$$
abc\stackrel{(12)}\to bac\stackrel{(13)}\to cab
$$
But it is true that $(132)=(12)\cdot(13)$:
$$
abc\stackrel{(13)}\to cba\stackrel{(12)}\to bca.$$

The product of a transposition with itself is the identity. The transposition $(ij)$ swaps element $i$ with element $j$. Doing this a second time will return the elements to their original places.